# Torus filled with disk

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, low-dimensional-topology

Let I have a torus $T^2$, I am taking two meridian circle say $m_1$ and $m_2$ now I am attaching boundry of two different disk with the meridian circle $m_1$ and $m_2$, my question is is it deformation retract to $S^2 \vee S^2$.?

My attempt
For me answer is yes.. I am deformed two meridian disk to a point and and I moved to one point to another without leaving the surface.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that would just leave $S^2$? This is all possible embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, where the complement has just one connected "inside" and one connected "outside".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your topological space (I will call it $X$) does not deformation retract to $S^2 \vee S^2$, for two different reasons.

***First reason:*** There does not exist any embedding $S^2 \vee S^2 \hookrightarrow X$, which is necessary for the existence of a [deformation retraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retraction_(topology)) $X \mapsto S^2 \vee S^2$. To see why no such embedding exists, consider the $\vee$ point of $S^2 \vee S^2$, let me call that point $P$. This point $P$ has a closed neighborhood $N \subset S^2 \vee S^2$ such that the frontier of $N$ is a disjoint union of two circles, and $N$ itself is homeomorphic to the cone on those two circles. But with a little thought and work one can prove that there does not exist any subset of $X$ that is homeomorphic to $N$ (a little algebraic topology helps to prove this).

***Second reason:*** $X$ is not homotopy equivalent to $S^2 \vee S^2$, which is also necessary for the existence of a deformation retraction $X \mapsto S^2 \vee S^2$. The reason is that $H_1(X;\mathbb Z)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$ whereas $H_1(S^2 \vee S^2;\mathbb Z)$ is trivial. But $H_1(\,\cdot\,;\mathbb Z)$ is a homotopy invariant.